# Adobe Flash Player Disabled

Tags: 16.04, flash, adobe

I am new to Linux (and very green). I have installed Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to play Amazon Prime Music. When I try, I get an error message saying Adobe Flash player is disabled. I searched for solutions and found dozens including loading Google Chrome. Running apts from the command line, etc. Nothing works. Any (easy) suggestions.

Comment: Click to the left of the address field in your web browser. It should open a menu from which you can allow Flash for the site in question.

Comment: Do you have Adobe Flash installed as a plug-in to your browser? I use Firefox, and it doesn't ship with it. You have to install AF separately.

Comment: I installed Google Chrome, which is supposed to come with Flash. So I can run Chrome, and I can watch and listen to Amazon videos, but I still get the error message "Flash disabled" when I try Amazon Music.

Comment: Is there any other videos are getting played from browser which need adobe flash player to run ? Also you can externally download flash player from official site and it will works.

Comment: I don't use Google Chrome (or Google anything if I can help it). I advise switching to Firefox which is a decent browser, but you will have to download and install AF. Alternatively stick with Chrome, download and reinstall AF and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I tried clicking on the address line to enable Flash. I changed the setting from Ask to Allow, but it still does not work. I get this error message: Adobe Flash is Disabled Adobe Flash is required to play this music. To stream music on Amazon Music for Web without any plugins, please use the latest versions of one of the following browsers: Chrome, Safari, Edge, Safari, and Firefox on Windows and Mac.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar Hjalmarsson. I did as you suggested and Firefox enabled the Flash player. Everything works correctly now.